# Task grouping in Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have an airflow DAG, with dependencies: start_task >> group1, start_task >> group2.

Tasks lie in the "tasks" dictionary and are used to fill out groups of tasks in the DAG

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from python.etl.dag_param_generator import DAGParamGenerator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

dag_param_generator = DAGParamGenerator('TEST_DINAMIC_DAG')
tasks = {
    "task_1": EmptyOperator(task_id="task_1"),
    "task_2": EmptyOperator(task_id="task_2"),
    "task_3": EmptyOperator(task_id="task_3"),
    "task_4": EmptyOperator(task_id="task_4")
}

with DAG(
    dag_id=dag_param_generator.get_dag_params('dag_id'),
    schedule=dag_param_generator.get_dag_params('schedule'),
    start_date=dag_param_generator.get_dag_params('start_date'),
    catchup=dag_param_generator.get_dag_params('catchup')
) as dag:
    start_task = EmptyOperator(task_id="start_task")

    with TaskGroup("group1") as group1:
        for key, value in tasks.items():
            if key in ['task_1', 'task_2']:
                print(value)
                globals()[key] = value
    with TaskGroup("group2") as group2:
        for key, value in tasks.items():
            if key in ['task_3', 'task_4']:
                print(value)
                globals()[key] = value
                
    start_task >> group1
    start_task >> group2
```

Tasks don't fit in groups, and I get the following result(groups are empty):
[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by `globals()` there and why are you double looping. Instead, add task to the group.

```
with TaskGroup("group1") as group1:
    for key in ['task_1', 'task_2']:
        group1.add(tasks[key])
with TaskGroup("group2") as group2:
    for key in ['task_3', 'task_4']:
        group2.add(tasks[key])
```

As to `globals()`: The act of creating a variable named `task_1` in global does *not* create a task. Running *the constructor* of the task, i.e. `EmptyOperator()` creates a task. You could have an array of lambdas if you want late execution. As in:

```
tasks = {
    "task_1": lambda:  EmptyOperator(task_id="task_1"),
    "task_2": lambda: EmptyOperator(task_id="task_2"),
    "task_3": lambda: EmptyOperator(task_id="task_3"),
    "task_4": lambda: EmptyOperator(task_id="task_4")
}

   with TaskGroup("group1") as group1:
        for key in ['task_1', 'task_2']:
            tasks[key]()
    with TaskGroup("group2") as group2:
        for key in ['task_3', 'task_4']:
            tasks[key]()
```

Comment: When I tried to run the code with your fix, I got an error: 
AttributeError: 'TaskGroup' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/task_group.py#L211 that happens when writing from memory